# Get a date range covering 2 business weeks starting with current monday

Tags: php, datetime

I am having trouble adjusting a week range in PHP.
I have it working to show the current work week starting on monday.
So for this week it shows 11/29/2010 - 12/03/2010.

I need to modify this to start from the current work week's monday and show and end date of two fridays from the monday.

So for example currently it would show a start date of 11/29/2010 and and end date of 12/10/2010.

Here is my code

```
<?
$timestamp = time();
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime("this monday", $timestamp));
echo " - ";
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime("Next Friday", $timestamp));
?>
```

How do I add +7 to "Next Friday"

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `this monday` to construct date time,
as it went pass Monday, it return next Monday

here is my suggestion

```
<?
$current_wkday = date('N', time());
switch ($current_wkday)
{
  /* assuming on sunday, get next monday */
  case 0:  $this_monday = strtotime('+1 day'); break;
  case 1:  $this_monday = time(); break;
  default: $this_monday = strtotime('-'.($current_wkday-1).'day'); break;
}

echo date("m/d/Y", $this_monday); /* 11days = 7+(5-1) */
echo " - ";
echo date("m/d/Y", $this_monday+(86400*11));
?>
```

Comment: Drew's comment below worked, but like you said because today is tuesday. When next monday comes around it would have pushed the end date out another week, instead of staying in the same range. I believe yours is the complete solution, and i appreciate it. I have studied it and understand most of it. I don't see how the middle section works. If you see this again, and have the time I would appreciate the explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design - The middle part is to assume if current date is Monday, **this Monday** is today. If current date is Sunday, assuming, you would need to use +1 day for **this Monday** instead . Otherwise, any day pass Monday is same as current_weekday-1 (such as Tuesday, to get this Monday, is -1, Wednesday is -2, and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `strtotime("Next Friday", $timestamp)` do `strtotime("Next Friday", $timestamp) + 60*60*24*7` (add the number of seconds in a week).

Comment: won't this start over on the second monday instead of staying in the original 2 week range?

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design: I was only concerned with the question: How do I add +7 to "Next Friday". Didn't actually test anything else :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just realised that "previous monday" only works the current day is tuesday or later...but it's a starting point for you..

```
<?php
    $monday = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("previous monday"));
    $friday = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($monday . " + 11 days"));
    echo $monday . ' - ' . $friday ;
?>
```

Comment: Drew - thanks man, this was a good starting point, actually all I did was change "previous monday" to "this monday". It seems to work, but Ill keep an eye on it.